# Subscript spacing using knitr and RStudio Markdown

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio, mathjax, r-markdown

I've created and RMarkdown file in RStudio. I've inserted this code in my RMarkdown file.

```
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n c x_k
&=cx_1+cx_2+\cdots+cx_n\\
&=c(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n)\\
&=c\sum_{k=1}^nx_k
\end{align*}$$
```

Compiling with knitHTML, I get the following image.

[image]

Note how the subscript k is crammed too tightly against x. Of course, I can try:

c x_{\,k}

but then it is a bit too far. I am wondering why the code x_k doesn't work the spacing as it does normally in latex.

Any suggestions?

D.

P.S. For those wanting the RMarkdown source and resulting html file:

[CovarianceAndCorrelation.Rmd](http://msemac.redwoods.edu/~darnold/math15/spring2013/R/Activities/CovarianceAndCorrelation.Rmd)

[CovarianceAndCorrelation.html](http://msemac.redwoods.edu/~darnold/math15/spring2013/R/Activities/CovarianceAndCorrelation.html)

Comment: (1) do you mean `knit2html()` ? (2) I'm guessing this is some kind of HTML rendering problem.  Looks fine for me with R-devel, knitr 1.5, Firefox 23 on Ubuntu 12.04 ... or with RStudio 0.98.447, using the "knit HTML" button (which may be what you meant), and viewing in RStudio's built-in HTML viewer ... can you post your HTML output somewhere?

Comment: I am viewing the html file in Safari 5.1.10. Links added to question above for those who want the RMarkdown source and the resulting html file.

Comment: Hmmm.... Today I am getting a good image. Weird.

Comment: Your HTML looks fine to me on Safari 5.1.10 (6534.59.10), e.g. under "Alternate Formula for the Correlation" ...

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy. Take H2O for example. Implement the following code:

`H~2~o`